# Tags are removed from Azure Data Factory when using GIT integration för publish

Tags: deployment, azure-data-factory, azure-deployment

In my company it is said that the infrastructure part, resource group and the Azure Data Factory (ADF), should be set up with Terraform by the Infrastructure team. As this is done they are also including Tags to the ADF and all looks correct when deployed to UAT environment.

My development team is supposed to include **the content** of the ADF. We use GIT integration and the, by Microsoft, recommended way of deploying our ADF by publishing our content to the adf_publish folder. Then the ARM template is deployed to UAT environment.

After deployment of ARM template the, by Infrastructure team, included Tags has been removed.

Is there any way to make sure the Tags remains?

Further, the other way, we have included global parameters as part of our content and when the Infrastructure team redeploys the infrastructure parts, they are removed from our content.

Is it possible to mitigate?

And, we are using Azure Devops Release Pipeline for deploying the ARM template.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the same prob.

If you use AzureCloud Agent to build just add this under your ADF zureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment:

```
            - task: AzurePowerShell@5
              inputs:
                azureSubscription: "${{ variables.azureResourceManagerConnection }}"
                scriptType: "inlineScript"
                inline: "New-AzTag -ResourceId ${{ variables.RessourceId }} -Tag @{ ${{ variables.Tags }} }"
                azurePowerShellVersion: "LatestVersion"
                pwsh: true
              displayName: "Re-apply tags for the created ressource"
```

Otherwise if you use on prem. agent to build your pipeline:
1- Install Powershell core : https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v7.1.3

2- Make sure to restart your agent (IMPORTANT)

3- Test pwsh command in your new powershell

4- Install the last version of Az.Resources

```
Install-Module -Name Az.Resources
```

5- Good luck...

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-aztag?view=azps-6.0.0

***NB:***
i use a file per environnement to manage tags per env.

```
variables:
  - template: templates/vars-${{ parameters.environment }}.yml
```

Inside var file:

```
variables:
  env_short: 'd'
  Tags: '"env"="d"; "name"="datalake"'
```